# Как в функцию передать указатель на двумерный массив?

Tags: массивы, указатели, c++

```
void vqvod(int *arr)
{
   ... // тут цикл
   cout<<arr[i][j];
   ...
}
int main()
{
   int a[n][m]; //вот с этим массивом нужно в функции работать
   ...
   vqvod(a);
   ...
}
```

Так не работает.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Надо при объявлении функции указывать размер меньшего измерения массива:

```
void vqvod(int arr[][m]){
   ... // тут цикл
   cout<<arr[i][j];
   ...

}
```

Или с указателем:

```
void vqvod(int* arr[m]){
   ... // тут цикл
   cout<<arr[i][j];
   ...

}
```

С простым указателем:

```
void vqvod(int * arr){
     ... // тут цикл
     cout << *( arr + i*m + j); // строчка для долгих раздумий
     ...    
}

int main() {
...
   vqvod ((int*) a); //вот так нужно вызывать функцию    
...
}
```

Comment: тогда указатель не нужен, а мне по заданию в универе, нужно использовать указатели

Comment: Добавил с указателем

Comment: насчёт строки для долгих раздумий, я не понимаю почему нужно умножать счетчик на размер, причем второй счетчик просто прибавлять, а второй размер вобще игнорировать?

Comment: Ну так я же написал - для долгих раздумий. Разберешься в ней - разберешься в многомерных массивах.

Comment: Не понял. Что передается в функцию из main?

Answer (score 2):

Я передаю матрицу в функцию так:

```
int lines = 3, columns = 4;
double ** Matrix = new double * [lines];
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    Matrix[i] = new double[columns];
```

А, затем, передача в функцию:

```
fun(Matrix, lines, columns);
```

Прототип функции:

```
void fun(double**, int, int);
```

Не забудьте потом освободить память:

```
for(int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
{
    delete [] Matrix[i];
    Matrix[i] = 0;
}
delete [] Matrix; 
Matrix = 0;
```

Если к указателю  Matrix больше не обращаются, то
можно 0 не присваивать.

Comment: Только вот у автора вопроса действительно матрица (элементы лежат в памяти вплотную друг к другу), а у Вас ее **модель на указателях**. 

У Вас в памяти вместе лежат элементы каждой строки, а между строками м.б. промежутки. И адрес начала (Matrix, то что передаете в функцию) это не адрес первого элемента первой строки.

При работе с такой структурой по индексам все будет хорошо, а при попытке что-то с ней сделать, как с единым куском памяти все сломается.

Это обязательно надо учитывать.

Comment: Я с указателем на указатели работаю уже лет тридцать, и ни разу ничего не ломалось. Зачем работать с матрицей  "как с единым куском памяти"? Зачем передавать в функцию адрес Matrix[0][0] таким неочевидным способом, а не &Matrix[0][0]?

Comment: О, значит мы ровесники ! Очень приятно.

Не понял насчет **неочевидный**. Вы передаете f(Matrix,n,m); Это самый очевидный и естественный путь, я не имел в ввиду ничего другого. При вызове f() в стек занесется адрес начала Matrix, вот что я написал.

Кому и зачем работать  с матрицей, как с единым куском ? Например функции, обменивающейся данными по сети, делающей контрольную точку и т.п. 

На самом деле тут (при правильном согласовании типов аргументов) ошибка не возникнет (если пинками не вгонять), но эффективность ниже.

Comment: Вряд ли мы с Вами ровесники, уважаемый @avp. Я-то с 1941 года. Началам программирования учен "с голоса", потом только подчитал кое что. Поэтому про "контрольную точку" и сетевые программы и не слыхивал. Специализировался на наукоемких программах (QuickBasic и TurboC вначале), потом на Oracle и FireBird (С++, С++Builder6).

Comment: Да, я с 59, все больше околосистемные программки на С. А начинал с FORTRAN и PL/I.

Comment: А я-то думал, что я здесь самый старый

Comment: А вообще, это все дело вкуса. Хотя создавать многомерные массивы методом, предложенным уважаемым BuilderC, на мой взгляд, довольно не рационально. 1. Это делается в несколько раз и, следовательно, занимает больше ресурсов. 2. Можно запутаться. Но если и того, и другого не бояться, то - дело вкуса. Но тут у человека была конкретная (учебная) задача. Я помог ее решить.

Comment: Создавать многомерные динамические массивы, нормально индексируемые, а не вычисляемые с помощью адресной арифметики (вот, где можно запутаться), следует лишь так, по-моему. /В.В.Подбельский "Язык С++", М."Финансы и статистика", 1999 г, стр. 156./ 
Что касается "запутаться", то программирование и вообще-то дело сложное... Если бы я знал какая там путаница ужасная, то ни почем бы не начинал :)