# Не работает созданный массив

Tags: c

Почему после создания 2d массива, в функции, где присваивается, возвращаемый функцией массив, функция видит только первую строку массива?

```
int main() {
    double** Aex;
    int numOfRows = readIntoExtendedMatrixFromTheFile(&Aex);

    destroyExtendedMatrix(Aex, numOfRows);
    return 0;
}

int readIntoExtendedMatrixFromTheFile(double*** Aex) {
    int numOfRows;
    FILE* resourceFile = fopen("C:\\forCpp\\slau.txt","r+"); 
    fscanf(resourceFile, "%d", &numOfRows);
    *Aex = createExtendedMatrix(numOfRows);
    printf("%lf\n", *Aex[0][0]); //РАБОТАЕТ
    printf("%lf\n", *Aex[1][0]); //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ

    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfRows; i++){
        printf("%d\n", i);
        for(int j = 0; j < numOfRows+1; j++){
            printf("%d\n", j);
            fscanf(resourceFile, "%lf", &(*Aex[i][j])); 
            printf("%lf ", *Aex[i][j]);
        }
    }*/

    fclose(resourceFile);

    return numOfRows;
}

double** createExtendedMatrix(int n) {
    double** Aex = (double**)calloc(n, sizeof(double*));

    if(Aex == NULL) abort();

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        Aex[i] = (double*)calloc(n+1, sizeof(double));

    printf("%d\n", Aex[1]);
    Aex[0][0] = 5; //РАБОТАЕТ
    Aex[1][0] = 6; //РАБОТАЕТ
    return Aex;
}
```

Comment: Скажите где, конкретно, проблема? Приведите строчку

Comment: printf("%lf\n", *Aex[1][0]); //НЕ РАБОТАЕТ примерно 15-16 строка

Comment: Вы можете уточнить, что значит "не работает" - выводит неправильное значение, программа падает с ошибкой или что-то ещё?

Comment: Не выводит вообще ничего + программа заканчивается, хотя выше строчка но с другими индексами(0,0) выводит значение

Comment: По `double***` компилятор не может определить размерность массива, соответственно и длину одной "строчки"

Comment: А как указать компилятору недостающую информацию ?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45324/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом коде происходит неправильное разыменование указателя.
Конструкция `*Aex[1][0]` интерпретируется как "содержимое памяти, на которую указывает 0-й элемент 1-го массива указателей на `double`". А должно быть "значение 0-го элемента, на который указывает 1-й элемент массива указателей, адрес 0-го массива содержится в `Aex`". Причина в том, что приоритет `[]` выше чем приоритет `*`.

Чтобы заставить этот код корректно работать необходимо явно указать порядок операций:

```
printf("%lf\n", (*Aex)[1][0]);
```