# С++ Почему ошибка при передачи указателя на двумерный массив в функцию?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, динамические-массивы

Нужно передать в функцию указатель на двумерный массив. Сделал это, как было предложено в одном из ответов вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/45349/278237). Но компилятор выдает ошибку. Почему?

```
    #include <cstdlib> // для system
    #include <math.h>  // математические функции. 
    #include <stdio.h> // стандартные функции ввода-вывода;
    using namespace std;
    void search_(int *A, int n, int m)
    {
       int i, MiN = 0, MiM = 0;
       int Mi = 0;
       cout << "Поиск элементов" << endl;
        for(int i=0; i<m; i++){
            for(int j=i;j<m;j++) {
                 if((A[i][j]<Mi)&&!(i==j)){ // Поиск минимального элемента в матрице
                    Mi = A[i][j];    
                    MiN = i;
                    MiM = j;
                    cout << A[i][j] << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << "\t\t";
                 }
            }
         cout << endl;
        }     
    }
    int main() 
    {     
        int n = 5, m = 5;    // n, m – размеры массива
        int **A;
        A = new int *[n];    // Захват памяти под указатели
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
            A[i] = new int [m];    // и под элементы    
        Mi = A[0][0];
        srand(time(NULL)); // Необходимо для генерации случайных чисел
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Вывод матрицы
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
               A[i][j] = rand() % 41 - 20; // Заполнение матрицы  
               cout << A[i][j] << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << "\t\t";
            }
        cout << endl;
        }
        A = search_((int*) A, n, m);
        cout << "Минимальный элемент " << Mi << "[" << MiN << "]" << "[" << MiM << "]" << endl; // Вывод найденного минимального элемента
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)  
            delete []A[i];    // Освобождение памяти
        delete []A;
        return 0;
    }
```

**Ошибка:**

> In function 'void search_(int*, int, int)': Line 14: error: invalid
>   types 'int[int]' for array subscript compilation terminated due to
>   -Wfatal-errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, если уж вы делаете реальный `int**`

```
    A = new int *[n];
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) 
        A[i] = new int [m];    // и под элементы
```

то и функцию делайте соответствующую:

```
void search_(int **A, int n, int m)
```

Comment: А как передать в функцию  `A = search_((int*) A, n, m);`?

Comment: Если функция будет от `int**`, то просто передаете `search_(A,n,m)`

Comment: В моём случае было необходимо дополнить `search_((int**) A, n, m)`

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем...

Comment: Исправил, в обоих вариантах результат один