# Двумерный массив в функции

Tags: c++, c

Имею задачу написать код, отсортировать элементы двумерного массива по столбцам.

Имею функцию `void Sort(int mas[N_suits][N_ranks], int array_size){...}`

При ее вызове из мейна `Sort(in_hand[N_suits][N_ranks], Number_of_cards_in_hand);` выводится сообщение о том, что аргумент типа int несовместим с параметром типа int(*)[].
Возникает вопрос, как в принципе, передать двумерный массив в функцию?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45324/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2?rq=1

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в функцию передать указатель на двумерный массив?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45324/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да так и передавать - если 1. размеры определены во время компиляции, 2. совпадают - то просто передать имя массива -

```
Sort(in_hand, Number_of_cards_in_hand);
```

Вот пример объявления такой функции, массива и передачи: https://ideone.com/BtKfVL

Comment: Теперь возникает вопрос в другом. Скрин прикрепил.
https://imgur.com/szJyE6g

Comment: Дайте текстом и полный файл. У меня подозрение, что у вас коллизия имен...

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/HJ05PwrHU

Comment: Передавать так - именем, а объявлять в функции тип - как массив. Вы понимаете разницу между объявлением функции и вызовом? Вы объявили в результате `Sort` не как функцию, в которую передают массив, а как получающую `int`! Ну какой у `int`'а может быть индекс? Объявить ее нужно как `void Sort(int mas[N_suits][N_ranks], int array_size)`. Вызывать ее нужно не как у вас - `Sort(in_hand[N_suits][N_ranks], Number_of_cards_in_hand);`, а `Sort(in_hand, Number_of_cards_in_hand);` Вы вообще мой ответ читали?! Там будет еще масса других ошибок - например, с `Check`у вас иная, но очень похожая проблема..

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что ваши `[N][M]` в объявлении функции бесмысленны. Компилятор всё равно распознает их как `[][]`.

Comment: @0andriy Только второй, но не первый.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
// Так у тебя для каждой размерности будет инстанцироваться своя функция
template<size_t N, size_t M>
void Sort(int (&mas)[N][M], ... ) { ... }

Sort(in_hand, Number_of_cards_in_hand);

// Или как у тебя изначально написано, но ВЫЗЫВАТЬ вот так.
// Сигнатуру оставить как в вопросе:
void Sort(int mas[N_suits][N_ranks], int array_size){...}

Sort(in_hand, Number_of_cards_in_hand);
```

Первый вариант, естественно, только для С++. По факту там я передаю ссылку на массив в функцию.